# Finding valid keys in a cryptosystem (m^k + mod 41)

Tags: cryptography

I'm studying for an exam I have tomorrow and could not find the answer to the following question:

For which of the following values of k is 
$$
E_{k}(m) = m^{k} mod 41
$$
a cipher over 
$$
Z_{41}
$$
?

And the possible values of k is: 3, 5, 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by a *cipher* you mean a bijection, then both $k=3$ and $k=7$ work because they are prime with $40=\phi(41)$, but $k=5$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

5 doesn't work because it divides 40 (which is phi(41)); so 5 has no multiplicative inverse mod 40.  3 and 7 are relatively prime to 40 so in each of these cases there is a multiplicative inverse (and therefore a bijection).